# Select multiple counts from one database table in one sql command access

Tags: sql, ms-access, select

I have a single table in the following format:

```
STATE SURVEY_ANSWER  
NC high  
NC moderate  
WA high  
FL low  
NC high
```

I am looking for a single query that will get me the following result:

```
STATE HIGH MODERATE LOW 
NC 2 1 0  
WA 1 0 0  
FL 0 0 1
```

Unfortunately, these are the results I am getting:

```
STATE HIGH MODERATE LOW 
NC 3 1 1  
WA 3 1 1  
FL 3 1 1
```

Here is the code I am using:

```
Select mytable.STATE,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mytable WHERE mytable.survey_answer = 'low' and state = mytable.state) AS low,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mytable WHERE mytable.survey_answer = 'moderate' and state = mytable.state) AS moderate,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mytable WHERE mytable.survey_answer = 'high' and state = mytable.state) AS high,
FROM mytable
GROUP BY mytable.state;
```

While this and other forums have been very helpful I am unable to figure out what I am doing wrong.  PLEASE NOTE: I am using Access so CASE WHEN solutions do not work.  Thank you for any advice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like this may be an issue caused by not using table aliases. Because you are doing sub-queries on the same table that the outer `SELECT` is using and not giving the outer table an alias, both of the conditions in the `WHERE` of the sub-query are only using data in the sub-query.

In other words, when you write:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mytable WHERE mytable.survey_answer = 'low' and state = mytable.state
```

It doesn't know anything about the outer query.

Try this:

```
SELECT t1.STATE,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mytable t2 WHERE t2.state = t1.state AND t2.survey_answer = 'low') low,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mytable t3 WHERE t3.state = t1.state AND t3.survey_answer = 'moderate') moderate,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mytable t4 WHERE t4.state = t1.state AND t4.survey_answer = 'high') high,
FROM mytable t1
GROUP BY t1.state
```

Answer (score 2):

Aiias answer explains why your current query is not working, but I thought I'd point out that your assumption that you can't use `CASE WHEN` solutions is only partly right, yes you can't use `CASE WHEN` but that doesn't mean you need correlated subqueries. You could simply use:

```
SELECT  mytable.STATE,
        SUM(IIF(mytable.survey_answer = 'low', 1, 0) AS low,
        SUM(IIF(mytable.survey_answer = 'moderate', 1, 0) AS moderate,
        SUM(IIF(mytable.survey_answer = 'high', 1, 0) AS high
FROM    mytable
GROUP BY mytable.state;
```