# How do I select distinct values in a column then display the total of a derived column?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

For a homework assignment, I need to write a query that displays distinct types of inventory (coffee, tea, or NULL) and the sum of their total value (inventory*price), so it should be a 3x2 table after the query is run. The full question is: "Create a new query, called CoffeeTotal.sql, which will summarize the price of each Item type (Coffee and Tea). Use a CASE statement and display the results by Item type. CONVERT the “Total Value” as a “$”. "

I know the output should be:

```
Coffee | $1242571.75
Tea    | $211716.70
NULL   | $1455288.45
```

But I'm struggling on writing the query. Currently, my attempt is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ItemType AS "Product Type",
    SUM(CASE WHEN ItemType = 'Coffee' THEN Price*OnHand),
    SUM(CASE WHEN ItemType = 'Tea' THEN Price*OnHand),
    SUM(CASE WHEN ISNULL(ItemType) THEN Price*OnHand)
FROM Inventory
```

But I'm 100% sure this code is wrong and I am completely in the dark on how to add in the '$' at this point. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You want [`GROUP BY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-group-by-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) not `DISTINCT`. Have a read of the documentation I linked, and post your new attempt if you fail (again).

Comment: you need pivoting...see this question [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54438788/how-to-select-count-of-multiple-columns) question of mine, the first answer has helped me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible approach, using `GROUP BY` with `CASE` and [FORMAT()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function (if you use SQL Server 2012+):

Input:

```
CREATE TABLE #Inventory (
    ItemType varchar(10),
    Price numeric(10, 2),
    OnHand int
)
INSERT INTO #Inventory
    (ItemType, Price, OnHand)
VALUES
    ('Coffee', 1.02, 21),
    ('Coffee', 1.02, 22),
    ('Coffee', 1.02, 23),
    ('Coffee', 1.02, 24),
    ('Tea', 2.01, 11),
    ('Tea', 2.01, 12),
    ('Drink', 3.03, 1),
    (NULL, 13.13, 3)
```

T-SQL:

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN ItemType <> 'Coffee' AND ItemType <> 'Tea' THEN NULL
        ELSE ItemType
    END AS ItemType,
    FORMAT(SUM(Price * OnHand), '$0.00') AS Total
FROM #Inventory
GROUP BY 
    CASE 
        WHEN ItemType <> 'Coffee' AND ItemType <> 'Tea' THEN NULL
        ELSE ItemType
    END
```

Output:

```
ItemType    Total
NULL        $42,42
Coffee      $91,80
Tea         $46,23
```